# npm install -g versus local

Tags: node.js, npm

I clone a git repo to my local, and run `npm install`, it worked. What's the different running npm install vs `npm install -g`? Why would I need to run `npm install -g` to a repo? unless it's a tool for example nodemon I would like to install globally because I want to use them everywhere.

Comment: Like you said, you should just use `npm install` for individual repos. You should use `npm install -g` for things you would want to use everywhere such as command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install -g NAME` it install globally, but if you want to use it, you should use `npm link NAME` in folder where you have your project.